# Marie Curie fellowship - family allowance

Tags: marie-curie

Am I entitled for a family allowance if my family (a husband and children) don't live in the same country where my host institution is?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are. Source: Been in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read carefully the instructions, I think that it doesn't matter where they live, you have to show proofs that you are part of a family, but I do not think that when you start working, the host asks for proofs that they have moved to the host country. But I'm not 100% sure. Check also with the host institution, I am sure they already had similar experiences.